# Was Kyoko and Chizuru's first meeting ever shown in the manga?

Tags: yuru-yuri

In Episode 8 of Series I of the Yuru Yuri anime, Kyouko and Yui go the library and see Chizuru Ikeda, Chitose's twin, reading alone. Mistaking her for Chitose, Kyouko starts trying to get her attention, and gets more and more persistent as she's ignored. After finding out that Chizuru is Chitose's twin, Kyouko starts annoying her by acting overly friendly every time they meet, and taking delight in Chizuru's irritation.

Oddly, I have no memory of anything like this happening in the manga, yet late in the manga, Kyouko and Chizuru have the same kind of relationship they do in the anime. Specifically, in Intermission 18, Chizuru is annoyed to find Kyouko hiding in the bushes eavesdropping on her conversation with Himawari's sister Kaede, and Intermission 20, she snarls at Kyouko when she comes to the classroom to see Chitose. We do see in the manga that Chizuru feels Kyouko is coming between Chitose and Ayano, but what we see in those chapters seems much more specific than that.

Did any manga chapter have a story like the anime episode that showed Chizuru and Kyouko meet?

Comment: I think the reason you probably don't remember is because volumes 3-5 were not translated into English. Their meeting may be within those pages

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Even "unofficially"? I did notice that my "unofficial" translation has a weird gap where they repeated a run of chapters.

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I guess if you don't even remember your own meeting with Chizuru, my chances of getting an answer are pretty slim...

Comment: Aye, unofficially :(

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko I watched the anime on Crunchyroll, but I discovered the series after the official English translation of the manga was gone. It seemed like the anime embellished a bit, so I was wondering if Kyouko and Chizuru's first meeting was one of those embellishments or not.

Comment: JManga were beginning to publish it, but shut down :(

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Too bad, I'd love to support an official version of the Yuru Yuri manga (and possibly find out the answer to this question). Any chance of Crunchyroll Manga picking it up, do you know?

Comment: I haven't heard anything to say so, its possible though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this was shown in Chapter 35 of volume 4 of the original Japanese manga. The anime adaption only made minor changes, such as the place of their meeting is changed from the school library to a local public library, and Yui's Kanji exercise book is seen with different contents.

You can refer to [this page](http://homepage3.nifty.com/hysk/yryrdb/e35.htm) for detailed information. I personally find this "Yuru Yuri database" site very useful in answering questions like yours, so please allow me to recommend it to any of the Yuru Yuri fans here.

Also, since a long time has passed after this question is first asked, it is highly possible that amateur English translations are out there right now. Maybe I should not provide a link for copyright reasons, but googling will certainly lead you to one.

Comment: Now I'm really glad I didn't delete this question a year ago when I thought about doing it! Thanks a lot for your answer. We do discourage posting links to scans here, so good call on that.